# Using document.createElement onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have done my own page and am now trying to add some javascript to it. What I want to do is when I click on a p tag inside div it should create a black div with ~70% opacity that covers the whole page and over that layer it should create an alertbox with some text that you can close so both the alertbox and black div disappear. So far I've just tried to create the black div but it doesn't work. I want to do this with only html ,css and javascript, not jquery.

In the HTML:

```
 <div class="varuhus">
     <p onclick="varuhusAlmhult()">Älmhult</p>
     <p onclick="varuhusStockholm()">Stockholm</p>
     <p onclick="varuhusMalmo()">Malmö</p>
 </div>
```

In the javascript(edited):

```
function varuhusAlmhult() {
var backgroundDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
document.body.appendChild(backgroundDiv);
backgroundDiv.style.width = "100%"
backgroundDiv.style.height = "100%"
backgroundDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
backgroundDiv.style.opacity = .7;
```

}

Comment: You're not doing anything with your newfound element, so what are you expecting ?

Comment: You want to use the `appendChild` method [(spec)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to add to your page.

Comment: @EmilCoder: you need to place created element somewhere, append it into eg. document + you have a typo in var name - should be `backgroundDiv`. And the last thing, don't forgot that empty div has 0 height and you don't see it.

Comment: @EmilCoder you have to append the DIV tag to body to make it visible. But note that you will have to also write more code so that it can be removed. Why don't you use JS libraries that do most of the job for you.

Comment: @CuriousMind How do I use the JS libraries you are talking about? As you might have noticed I am pretty new to this.

Comment: @humble.rumble thank you so much for taking your time! The only problem is that modal isnt centered on my own webpage and the overlay doesnt cover the whole page when scrolling. But I guess I am able to fix that myself. Thanks

Comment: @humble.rumble i changed position to fixed from absolute instead in .overlay Dont know if its wrong to do that but it worked. Still trying to get modal to be centered though, any idea?

Comment: @humble.rumble It works now! I added margin-left/right/top/bottom:auto; I just got one more question for you hehe, whats up with the ::before in the css? Ive never seen it before. How does it work since you got 2 css for overlay and modal?

Comment: @humble.rumble but why just not put it in the same part? Like everything in .overlay {} and .modal {} ?

Comment: @EmilCoder please find [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) as an example library. No doubt, you can do all this yourself, but there is no point in reinventing wheel.

Comment: Whoaa... thats not the point @humble.rumble. Many things were there before so many frameworks and languages. The point is why to spend time in reinventing something in the area, where solutions are already available.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an overlay
2. Append a modal
3. Append the overlay to the document
4. Upon click of the overlay (but not the modal), remove it
5. Then we style the overlay and modal with CSS

You can include more logic to insert a close button if you'd like

```js
function varuhusAlmhult() {
    var overlay = document.createElement("DIV");
    overlay.className = 'overlay';
    overlay.onclick = function() {
        overlay.remove();
    }
    var modal = document.createElement("DIV");
    modal.className = 'modal';
    modal.innerHTML = 'A bunch of text';
    overlay.appendChild(modal);
    document.body.appendChild(overlay);
}
```

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
.overlay::before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay::before,
.modal {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1rem;
    white-space: initial;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.modal {
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px -5px black;
}
```

```html
<p onclick="varuhusAlmhult()">Älmhult</p>
```